# When were 3-pin voltage regulators introduced?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, history

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere, i'll feel pretty dumb if someone is able to find it doing a quick google search. But.... I've had not luck. When were the first 3 pin voltage regulator ICs introduced?

Comment: You should read up on some of the personalities in the industry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Widlar

Comment: When you say "introduced", do you mean "invented" or "marketed"?

Comment: Alas this is still an open question. Both answers include the keyword term "probably". There are surprisingly no good sources on this. You'd think that Lojek's *History of Semiconductor Engineering* would cover it, but it doesn't. It does discuss the LM100 though.

Comment: By introduced I originally meant "invented," but I'd be interested to know when VRs were first marketed too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Bob Widlar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Widlar) designed the first monolithic IC linear regulator, the [µA723](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ua723.pdf) for Fairchild Semiconductor in 1967, and later designed the LM100 for National Semiconductor.

This is the same guy who designed the [first monolithic IC op-amp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Historical_timeline), the [µA702](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Widlar#.CE.BCA702_and_.CE.BCA709), also for Fairchild.

Sadly, you're not going to find many online references to these things, since they're all long-obsolete, replaced by jellybeans nearly as ancient.

Now, the 723 isn't a *three-terminal* regulator. It's adjustable and more complicated to use than the later LM117/317, which essentially replaced it. The first monolithic three-terminal fixed regulator is probably the [LM109/309](http://www.hep.upenn.edu/SNO/daq/parts/lm309h.pdf), released in 1969.

Comment: According to Lojek's book (see my comment under the question) the LM100 was the first monolithic regulator; also according to http://www.psma.com/sites/default/files/PowerElectronicsMilestones2011FebDraft.pdf it preceded the uA723. According to Lojek, Widlar had left Fairchild in 1965. The Wikipedia page (from which you probably got this info) cites a book by Harrison. But that book makes no mention of the 723!

Answer (score 3):

The first popular 3-terminal regulator was the 78XX series, introduced, if memory serves, by Fairchild as the \$\mu\$A78XX series ca. 1970. You can find the series listed in the 1973 Fairchild linear databook [here](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_fairchilddldLinearIntegratedCircuitsDataCatalog_30443462), so no later than 1972-73. By '73 they had already introduced the \$\mu\$A78MXX series as well.

The LM317 (adjustable three terminal regulator) also hails from this approximate period.

Possibly preceding the 78xx series was the 3-terminal LM309, a Widlar design, in 1969 according to [this](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/article/01mpel04-alookback.pdf). It was not as big a commercial success. I have my doubts about the thoroughness of the research that went into that reference- it does not mention Fairchild at all, and appears to be a National Semiconductor (RIP) centric view of history.

The 78xx series design is one of those that was done so well the first time and achieved such a wide acceptance that they are still used in vast quantities 40-45 years later, despite many competitive parts that perform better under one constraint or another.

Comment: The LM prefix was used by National Semiconductor. (Perhaps TI will continue making new "LM" designated devices.) It was a common practice to clone a design, then either replace or augment the manufacturer-specific prefix on the part number. Therefore, I expect, purely from the part number, that the Fairchild part number is the clone, not the original.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Do you have some evidence that shows the NS part preceded the Fairchild part?